# Pandas reading and sorting a file's content

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I am reading a file from SIPRI. It reads in to pandas and dataframe is created and I can display it but when I try to sort by a column, I get a `KeyError`. Here is the code and the error:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Student\\Documents')


#Find the top 20 countries in military spending by sorting
data = pd.read_excel('SIPRI-Milex-data-1949-2016.xls', 
header = 0, index_col = 0, sheetname = 'Current USD')
data.sort_values(by = '2016', ascending = False)
```

`KeyError: '2016'`

Answer (score 0):

1. I downloaded the file and looks like the 2016 is not a column itself so you need to modify the dataframe a bit so as to change the row of country to be the header.
2. The next thing is you need to say data.sort_values(by = 2016, ascending = False). treat the column name as an integer instead of a string.

> data = pd.read_excel('SIPRI-Milex-data-1949-2016.xlsx', 
>    header = 0, index_col = 0, sheetname = 'Current USD')
>
> ```
> data = data[4:]
>
> data.columns = data.iloc[0]
>
> data.sort_values(by =2016, ascending = False)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You get the key error because the column '2016' is not present in the dataframe. Based on the excel file its in the integer form. Cleaning of data must be done in your dataframe to sort the things.

You can skip the top 5 rows and the bottom 8 rows to get the countries, then replace all the string and missing values with `NaN`. The following code will help you get that.

```
data = pd.read_excel('./SIPRI-Milex-data-1949-2016.xlsx', header = 0, index_col = 0, sheetname = 'Current USD',skiprows=5,skip_footer = 8)
data = data.replace(r'\s+', np.nan, regex=True).replace('xxx',np.nan)
new_df = data.sort_values(2016,ascending=False)

top_20 = new_df[:20].index.tolist()
```

Output:

```
['USA', 'China, P.R.', 'Russian Federation', 'Saudi Arabia', 'India', 'France', 'UK', 'Japan', 'Germany', 'Korea, South', 'Italy', 'Australia', 'Brazil', 'Israel', 'Canada', 'Spain', 'Turkey', 'Iran', 'Algeria', 'Pakistan']
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Well this could be helpful, I guess:

```
data = pd.read_excel('SIPRI-Milex-data-1949-2016.xlsx', skiprows=5, index_col = 0, sheetname = 'Current USD')
data.dropna(inplace=True)
data.sort_values(by=2016, ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

And to get Top20 you can use:

```
data[data[2016].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, (int, float)))][:20]
```